# How to convert a large binary string to a binary value and back

Tags: php

I need to take a large binary string (whose length will always be divisible by 8) ...

```php
// 96-digit binary string
$str = '000000000011110000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000001111';
```

... then convert it to a binary value (to store in a mysql db as type `varbinary`), and later convert it back again to recreate that string.

This is most likely NOT a duplicate question. Every posted stackoverflow answer I could find is either broken (PHP7 apparently changed how some of these functions work) or doesn't offer a solution to this specific problem. I've tried a few things, such as ...

```php
// get binary value from binary string
$bin = pack('H*', base_convert($str, 2, 16));

// get binary string from binary value
$str2 = str_pad(base_convert(unpack('H*', $bin)[1], 16, 2), 96, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

... but this doesn't actually work.

My goal is to go back and forth between the given binary string and the smallest binary value. How is this best done?

Comment: Unless you plan to store very large numbers of these strings (i.e. into the billions) then don't muck about - just store a string as a string.

Comment: If it's an integer you should be able to just convert in 8-character chunks using a loop, from the ASCII into a "real" binary string.  bin1 = convert, binstr += bin1

Comment: A follow-up thought: your example is 96 bits long, which will exceed the native integer capacity of PHP on any platform. Rather than converting to a binary integer of arbitrary length and unknown support, compress the string with [gzdeflate()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php) or similar. For your sample above `gzdeflate()` returns a 17 character string, a saving of around 80%.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Your username checks out ... you've offered two very interesting and entirely perpendicular solutions :)

Comment: @DaveS Your approach makes sense ... if you feel like posting example code, the point is yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions convert bit strings to binary character strings and back.

```
function binStr2charStr(string $binStr) : string
{
  $rest8 = strlen($binStr)%8;
  if($rest8) {
    $binStr = str_repeat('0', 8 - $rest8).$binStr;
  }
  $strChar = "";
  foreach(str_split($binStr,8) as $strBit8){
    $strChar .= chr(bindec($strBit8));
  } 
  return $strChar;
}


function charStr2binStr(string $charStr) : string
{
  $strBin = "";
  foreach(str_split($charStr,1) as $char){
    $strBin .= str_pad(decbin(ord($char)),8,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  } 
  return $strBin;
}
```

usage:

```
// 96-digit binary string
$str = '000000000011110000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000001111';

$strChars = binStr2charStr($str);
// "\x00<\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x0f"

//back
$strBin = charStr2binStr($strChars);
```

Comment: Where `gzdeflate()` reduces the 96-char string to 17, this yields 12. For smallest possible result, this is the way to go. Thanks!